# Generic overload with params keyword results in recursive call

Tags: c#

Consider this code - two extension methods for an interface - one generic and one is not. This code is imported with a library [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture) and cannot be changed.

```
public interface IFixture
{
}

public static class FixtureFreezer
{
    //this is a real method within AutoFixture. The code is simplified though
    public static T Freeze<T>(this IFixture fixture) where T:new()
    {
        return new T();
    }

    //not a real method, added for test
    public static int Foo(this IFixture fixture)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now I wanted to create an overload for `Freeze<T>`. However this results in a recursive call - `fixture.Freeze<T>()` uses the params overload with empty array as params and not the parameterless overload.

```
public static class FixtureExtensions
{
    public static T Freeze<T>(this IFixture fixture, params object[] arguments)
    {
        // do something
        return fixture.Freeze<T>(); //recursion
    }
    public static int Foo(this IFixture fixture, params object[] arguments)
    {
        return fixture.Foo(); //no recursion
    }
}
```

I have created the non-generic `Foo` method for test and it is correctly resolved.

Is this behaviour correct? Can I somehow call the parameterless overload inside of my overload with params?

---

**NOTE**
The simplified version does not reflect the real situation. To reproduce the problem please download [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture).

Comment: Does behavior change if you add the `where T:new()` constraint in `FixtureExtions`'s `Freeze<T>` ?

Comment: @Fildor yeah it probably would, nice call

Comment: well, resolving extension-methods is done recursivly starting at your class you're currently in, which is your extension-class. As there already is a match, why search any further? Just searching for the dupe...

Comment: @Fildor it does in my simplified version, it doesn't in a real scenario. I will try to update the simplified version

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks. I was actually just _guessing_ that the compiler needs the type argument to have the same constraints for the match.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I am not sure if that dupe applies here. The dupe question was about a signature-identical extension to a Linq extension. These above have different parameter sets ...

Comment: @Fildor From Jons answer: "It will stop as soon as it finds any eligible extension methods" So I suppose that applies to all candidates. So searching stops as soon as a match was found.

Comment: Perhaps `if (arguments.Length == 0) { return FixtureFreezer.Freeze<T>(fixture); }` in `FixtureExtensions` would solve it for you?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I am running some probe now. It seems you are right, as long as one of the extension classes are not in the same namespace as the extended class itself. Which is basically, what Jon is sayin, too - am I right?

Comment: @Llama perfect <3 this is the solution